# select option to default after changed the option length

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, asp-classic

I got two **radio button that are yes and no**, so if i **click on yes** the **tr of div1** that is **radio button of dealer and consumer** will **show** from hide, whereas if i **click on no** it will **not show** up the two radio button as i just mention.

So now the condition is when i **click on yes and click on dealer radio button** the **select option of CATEGORY** have to change to **different value** as i coded in **function override** of javascript and also different value if i click on consumer radio button.

BUT if i **click on No radio button** i **wanted** to set the **CATEGORY select option to default value** as i coded in vbscript.

Let's say i **clicked yes and consumer radio button** the onchange function **change the option length to 1** so after that if i **click back on No radio button**,the **select option CANNOT change back** to the **default value** anymore.

Any solutions for this? Hope help and thank you.

```
<script language="Javascript">
function Override(value){
    var list = document.getElementById("selCATE");
    if (value == "1"){
        document.getElementById('selCATE').options.length = 1;
        list.add(new Option("Gift to consumers without proof of package sales","Gift to consumers without proof of package sales"));
        list.add(new Option("Gift to consumers without proof of package sales","Gift to consumers without proof of package sales"));
    }else if (value == "2"){
        document.getElementById('selCATE').options.length = 1;
        list.add(new Option("Gift to dealers","Gift to dealers"));
    }
}
   </script>

<input name="rdoGFLG" type="radio"  value="Y" onchange=""/>Yes
<input name="rdoGFLG" type="radio"  value="N" onchange="Override(this.value)"/>No

<tr id="div1">
    <td>
        <input name="rdoGTYP" id="rdoGTYP" type="radio" value="1"  onchange="Override(this.value);">Consumer
        <input name="rdoGTYP" id="rdoGTYP" type="radio" value="2" onchange="Override(this.value);">Dealer   
    </td>
</tr>

<td valign="top"><b>Category</b></td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
        <%
        objADO.openRecordSet
        strSQL = "SELECT catc from cogstc  a where cono='" & SQLEncode(StrCono) & "' and acti=1 order by posi "
        Set objRS= objADO.runQuery(StrSQL)

        if objRS.recordCount > 0 then
            Response.write "<td valign='top' align='left' width='50%'><select name='selCATE' class='NormalInputTextField'>"
            Response.write "<option value=''>Select One</option>"

            Do until objRS.EOF
                Response.write "<option value='" & objRS("catc") & "'>" & objRS("catc") & "</option>"
                objRS.MoveNext
            loop
        Response.write "</select></td>"
        end if
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a

```
list.selectedIndex=0;
```

where you want the list to return to default. The index is 0 based so the first element is 0 not 1. 1 is the second element. You can change 0 to -1 (negative one) if you want the list to select nothing.